# Error during publishing of web service for insertion and seaching of data in database

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rpc

First i created a webservice for simple get and set method and published that web service successfully. After that i created a websevice which have methods to insert and search data from oracle database using jdbc connection but when i am trying to publish this web service i am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" Server Runtime Error: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
        at com.bizmonks.services.BizMonksWSPublish.main(BizMonksWSPublish.java:10)
    Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModel.createJAXBContext(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModel.postProcess(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.RuntimeEndpointInfo.createSEIModel(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.RuntimeEndpointInfo.init(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    java.sql.Connection is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at java.sql.Connection

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModel$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 11 more
```

Could you please help me? I am not able to find out where i am doing wrong. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should pay attention to the `cause`of the exception that is what is likely the problem.

Comment: @Omoro yes, you are right, actually i tried many times but not able to identify the reason of this error.